# Elasticsearch Python client to add geo_point

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.2.0; however, I'm really struggling trying to add geo_point data. In fact, the the geocoded data get's added as a string.

Expected: **"geo":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point"}}}**

Actual: **"geo":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"string"}}}**

I'm adding the data in python the following way:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

# ... 
es_entries['geo'] = { 'location': str(data['_longitude_'])+","+str(data['_latitude_'])}
# ...

es.index(index="geodata", doc_type="doc", body=es_entries)
```

Is there any tutorial on adding geo_point data through python (this is not as simple as it may seem)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the `geo_point` type in the mapping while creating your index with [`es.indices.create()`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create).

That call takes a `body` argument containing the settings and mappings of your index.

```
mappings = {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "geo": {
                 "properties": {
                     "location": {
                         "type": "geo_point"
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
es.indices.create(index='geodata', body=mappings)

# ... 
es_entries['geo'] = { 'location': str(data['_longitude_'])+","+str(data['_latitude_'])}
# ...
es.index(index="geodata", doc_type="doc", body=es_entries)
```

**UPDATE ES7**

In ES7, document types are not necessary anymore, so the solution changes to this (no more `doc`):

```
mappings = {
    "properties": {
        "geo": {
             "properties": {
                 "location": {
                     "type": "geo_point"
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized that the "doc_type" and the mappings I created needed to match. I was using a different type name for my mapping. I realized that later on. Thanks!

Comment: Great you figured out!

Comment: this is not working anymore: tried today, got 'elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parse_exception', 'unknown key [doc] for create index')'

Comment: @besil you're probably running on ES7 which doesn't accept doc_type anymore. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Val, what is this "es_entries", is it an empty index?

Comment: @user it's just a hash that serves as the body to be sent in the index query

Comment: @Val, since few days I'm stuggling about mapping, could you pls help me? I posted question as "Why does geospatial data not convert from numbers to geo-point with Python client with Elastisearch? "

Comment: @user I see you already have a perfectly valid answer there...

Comment: @Val, I tried based on your explanations, but I'm wondering why I don't get the expected results. I may do some failure but I can't find it...May ask as a new question?

Comment: @user go ahead ans ask a new question, this one is closed anyway

Comment: @Val, pls see "Why mapping not working when data streaming?"

Answer (score 0):

With elasticsearch-dsl you should do like:

```
Class MyDoc(DocType):
    geo = GeoPoint()

# Geo-point expressed as an object, with lat and lon keys.
doc = MyDoc(geo={'lat': 52.5720661, 'lon': 52.5720661})
#or Geo-point expressed as a string with the format: "lat,lon".
doc = MyDoc(geo='52.5720661, 52.5720661')
# or Geo-point expressed as an array with the format: [ lon, lat]
doc = MyDoc(geo=[52.5720661,52.5720661])
```

I wouldn't use multiple formats but keep the same.

References:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/398